# how to pass Same page <select> value to Same page <f:param>?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have the following code:

```
<p:datatable>
    <p:rowExpansion>
        <table id="paymentProcess">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label> <h:outputText value="Type: *" /> </label>
                    <p:column headerText="Process Payment" style="width:10%">
                        <select id="type" onchange="change(this.value)"
                            name="type" style="width: 70px;height: 20px;font-size: small">   *********
                            <option id="check">Check</option>*****
                            <option id="cash">Cash</option>*****
                        </select>****
                    </p:column>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label> <h:outputText value="Check/DD Number: *" /> </label>
                        <input id="chkNo" maxlength="7"
                            style="font-size: small; width: 100px;height: 20px"/>
                </td>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label> <h:outputText value="Total: *" /> </label>
                    <input id="total" style="font-size: small; width: 100px;height: 20px"/>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <h:commandLink value="Pay Now"
                        actionListener="#{adminActionController.processPayment}">
                        <f:param name="productId" value="#{due.productId}" />
                        <f:param name="intimationid" value="#{due.id}" />
                        <f:param name="regiNo" value="#{due.regiNo}" />
                        <f:param name="uuid"
                            value="#{adminActionController.userBean.id}" />
                        <f:param name="checkNo" value=""/> *******
                    </h:commandLink>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

I want to pass select `id="type"` to `f:param name="checkNo" value="?"` How could I do this? When I click on the `commandLink`, it goes to `actionListener` method in a backing bean.
Is there another way to pass it to the backing bean when I click on the command link?

Comment: Why did you add the `[jsf-1.2]` tag if you aren't using JSF 1.2 at all?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using JSF you can use the `h:selectOneMenu` instead of the basic HTML `<select>` tag. As an alternative you can use PrimeFaces' `p:selectOneMenu`, this also has skinning capabilities.

For an example of this menu [see PrimeFaces' showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf).

For four examples how to pass additional parameters to a backing bean click [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/).